# UI Designing approch

Tags: android, user-interface, navigation-drawer

I was struggling with this design, requirement is like, Client wants to open side view on swipe of quick action button similar to DrawerLayout.

If i will go for DrawerLayout then it will allow me to open side menu on whole screen, other than this i was looking into a library [Slide Menu Layout](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6769) ,Any suggestion guys. your help will save my a-lot effort.[image]

Answer (score 1):

all the code for that library is on [github](https://github.com/JustKiddingBaby/SlideMenuLayout/tree/master/slidemenu/src/main/java/com/jkb/slidemenu) -
you can easily reimplement this functionality
1.inflate the view and add to canvas
2.listen for touch events and override them to interact with the canvas

that's all he's done in his library.